# Problem with binding 2 functions to a button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

First of all this is my code:

```
button_1 = Button(
        image=button_image_1,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda:[get_to_main_when_clicked(),delete_red_border()],
        relief="flat"
    )
```

As you can see I binded 2 functions to this button. To the first one: If a specific condition is true, then the function lets an image appear. The second one then should wait 3 seconds and should delete the appeared image. The only really weird problem is, that it no matter what I do, first executes the delete_red_border() function. It waits 3 seconds, then its trying to delete an image that couldn't be defined and globalized, because the get_to_main_when_clicked() function wasn't executed. How can I solve this?
PS: The specific condition is true.

Comment: Maybe instead of adding both functions in the command, just add the `get_to_main_when_clicked()` function, and at the end of `get_to_main_when_clicked()` you can use `after(3000, delete_red_border)`

Comment: Your `lambda` creates a list, the first item is evaluated first. I guess the problem is somewhere else ...

Comment: Yea I think I found the problem, I described it in a comment under the other answer, but yesss, BrianZhang you're totaly right, pretty obvious and a way easier solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: damn doesnt work either, I guess it's because the same problem

Comment: the window doesnt get refreshed till the function is done running

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Create a function specifically for this button. A function is much easier to understand and debug than a lambda, especially a complex lambda. You can then put any logic you want inside the function.

```
def do_something():
    get_to_main_when_clicked()
    delete_red_border()

button_1 = Button(..., command=do_something)
```

Comment: I already tried that, but I think I now know what the error is. It seems like that the first function is getting executed, but the window only gets refreshed once all the functions binded to the button are finished being executed. Can I bypass this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it. The problem was, that it didn't refreshed/updated the window after finishing the first function. That was solved by one line of code:

```
window.update()
```

Comment: yes, tkinter is single-threaded. While it's running a function it can't be updating the window.

Comment: generally it isn't good convention to call update() when you don't need to. If your program isn't too big, you can post it in your question and I can see if there's a better way to do it. Generally, you always want to use mainloop() to update your program.